# How to send Json Data from Aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, json.net

I tried to use TokenInput Jquery for multiple value autocomplete where it requires the JSON response as input data

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

I am using ASPX page as source

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#txtTest").tokenInput("Complete.aspx", {
        theme: "facebook"
    });

    });


</script>
```

**Edited From Here**
Question: How to provide the JSON data from a aspx page in the desired format as i have datatable with values according to Querystring from Complete.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["q"]))
    {
        string json = "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"name\": \"Test 1\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"name\": \"Test 2\"}]";
        Response.Clear(); 
        Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
        Response.Write(json); 
        Response.End();              

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is the json data is not going back to the javascript or you want a way to build json strings?

Comment: I am not sure on both the things as i am bind not to use firebug tools (IE8) but the data is not reaching in the JSON format to the javascript that is the main cause i think

Comment: IE8 has its own debugger tools, accessed via F12 key. Additionally, you can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to get full details on request and response.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie i dont have access to download any utility program on my desktop.I tried IE8 developer tools not much of help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to the `WCF`, you can create `WebMethod` in .aspx.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string Info()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string result = js.Serialize(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
        return result;
    }
```

and request this WebMethod via Ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/Info",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    },
                    type: "post",
                    dataType : "json"
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

EDIT:

Code-behind - Page_Load handler (JsonPage.aspx)

```
  string json = "[{\"name\":\"Pratik\"},{\"name\": \"Parth\"}]";
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  Response.Write(json);
  Response.End();
```

and request the `JsonPage.aspx` via *TokenInput* `jQuery`. (Sample.aspx & JsonPage.aspx are in same folder)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txt1").tokenInput("JsonPage.aspx");
        });
</script>

<body>
 <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, but i am using existing aspx page to get the data.And also want to use TokenInput jquery

Comment: @PratikGupta - You can use .aspx to write json. What's problem with .aspx page?

Comment: To the point i was doing the same except is missed the [] brackets to the returned data thts why returned json data was not in correct format. Thanks a lot AVD and i have updated my question also

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at WCF.  [WCF has native support for returning JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885100.aspx) and you don't have to worry about string concatenation or HTTP content types.

Comment: I want piece of code which can run under framework 2.0 as this module is a part of fix to the existing code.

Comment: In that case, you should probably look at using JayRock.  [MSDN has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx).

Comment: Well i need to give a try to the stated thing.Hope this should work for me.Thanks for your help chris.