# Unable to get the Text box value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery Tokeninput to select multiple values but when i tried to select the values in text box it's always coming blank I am using below Jquery function to retreive the val.
Please refer to to my previous question on stack [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613194/how-to-send-json-data-from-aspx-page)

```
  var values = $("#txtTest").val();
        $("#Button1").click(function() {
          alert(values);
            return false;
        });
```

Please find the screen shot or same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box is not actually what holds the selections its a list

```
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
      var txt = '';
      $("#txtTest").prev('ul').find('li:not(:last-child)').each(function(){
          txt += $(this).text()+ " ";
      });
      //alert(val());
      alert(txt);
        return false;
    });
```

EDIT

That's just a hack to get what you wanted but the library has a method to get the values in the list [`selector.tokenInput("get");`](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/#methods)

```
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
      var txt = '';
      $.each($("#txtTest").tokenInput('get'), function(){
          txt += this.id + " " + this.name;
      });
      //alert(val());
      alert(txt);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: It's working now ...Thanks a lot Musa. Can i ask to explain wht you did here because it seems little twisted.

Answer (score 1):

USe

var values = $("#txtTest").attr('value');